# Vim displaying a warning, although code compiles correctly

Tags: c, vim, gnu

Edit: to clarify, since someone attempted to edit this post, I do mean vim displays the warning, gcc does not.

I have a program that compiles correctly with no warnings with the following command line:

```
gcc -o stetest -pedantic -Wall strerrortest.c
```

However, vim warns me that I have an implicit declaration of strerror on the line indicated in the MWE below. Is this something I should be worried about, or is the fact that it compiles correctly sufficient? Should I write a prototype to get the warning to go away?

The warning is

```
implicit declaration of function 'strerror' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
```

Source below:

```
// strerrortest.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",strerror(1)); 
        // Vim complains about an implicit declaration of strerror here.
    return 0;
}
```

System is Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: vim warns you?? show the warning plz..

Comment: @Haris, added the warning.

Comment: Its compiling without any warnings in my machine, are you compiling this in a linux machine?

Comment: @Haris, yes, Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Sorry about the edit then!  I'm not 100% sure, but could it possibly have something to do with using `#define __GNU_SOURCE`? It definitely makes a difference for the reentrant version of strerror (which returns either a `char *` or an `int`), but the man pages mention nothing about the non-reentrant version...

Comment: How do you get vim to display such a warning? I mean, you must be using :make or have some kind of plugin. Vim doesn't compile code on its own and that is a compiler warning

Comment: @jgon this is **not** a warning created by vim but by gcc.

Comment: @FelixPalmen  gcc wont generate any warning for this . Code is correct as appear.

Comment: @trentcl There are plenty of vim plugins that use a compiler to analyze the code as you type it in.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm sure, but without knowing which plugin or what compiler flags it's using, we can't know how to fix it. Vim isn't generating this warning by itself so saying "Vim warns me about such and such" isn't enough information.

Comment: the posted code does not actually cleanly compile.  Always compile with all warnings enabled. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)  The warnings: parameter 'argc' not used and parameter 'argv[]' not used.  To fix, declare main as `int main( void )`

Comment: @ameyCU still it is a `gcc` warning message. Maybe some plugin calling `gcc` in a weird way so it doesn't see the `strerror` prototype.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, I am aware that gcc is being called under the hood, I was wondering what might this indicate is wrong with the source file (if anything), and whether I should do anything to fix it (like add a prototype).

Comment: @trentcl I am fairly sure the warning is the result of some plugin.

Comment: @user3629249: Do not! Instead use `(void)argc; (void)argv;` to tell the compiler you do not need it.

Comment: @jgon if the code shown is *exactly* your code, ameyCU and others are correct, there's nothing to fix. Except maybe the plugin you use ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen, thanks :) Any advice on that?

Comment: @Olaf,  that is not correct.  using your suggestion I.E. `int main( (void)argc, (void)argv )` results in two error messages from the gcc compiler:  `7:9:error: expected declaration specifier or '...' before '{' token`  and `7:19: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '{' token`  where line 7 contains the main declaration

Comment: @user3629249: I did not say that! It would be new syntax, if semicolons are allowed in an argument-list. I mean to put these as the very first (or last) statements of the function.

Comment: @jgon If you know what plugin is calling gcc, you may be able to set some option inside Vim to affect how gcc is invoked. If you don't know the name of the plugin, this question is a waste of time.

Comment: @Olaf,  Thanks for the info.  I have never used nor seen this method of getting the compiler to ignore a parameter before.  (and I have been programming C since back in the early 80's)

Comment: @user3629249: To be honest, I saw this some time ago on SO myself. Until then I used something like `argc = argc;`, which also works. Either way, I think it is a good idea to add a comment why you do not use the argument.

Answer (score -2):

the problem is the way your invoking the gcc compiler.

The command to vim should be:

```
!gcc -c strerrortest.c -o strerrortest.o -I/usr/include
```

However, several parts of that can be eliminated
by the proper entries in the vim.ini file

Comment: Why the down vote?  That is the correct vim command line to compile a file.  To link the file into an executable is slightly different, but the question was about compiling

Comment: The standard gcc for a target should have the paths integrated. It works on any normal platform. And as OP wrote, it actually **does** when compiling from the shell..

Comment: @juanchopanza,  Since the !gcc is the only way I know of to compile within vim, that is the answer I gave.  It is probably possible to install some addon that would supply a key sequence for compiling, but if so, then the addon is not setup correctly

Answer (score -4):

just replace with you code
`fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",strerror(1));`